OnclientClick and OnClick is not working at the same time in <asp:Button />?
<form id="form1" runat="server" method="post" class="needs-validation" novalidate="">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="txtEmail">Email</label>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtEmail" TextMode="Email" CssClass="form-control" TabIndex="1" ValidateRequestMode="Enabled" autofocus="autofocus" />
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
            Please fill in your email
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSubmit" ClientIDMode="Static" OnClientClick="return startTimer();"  CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"   UseSubmitBehavior="false"  OnClick="btnSubmit_Click"  Text="Submit" />
        <%--<asp:LinkButton ID="btnSubmit" type="submit" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click"  CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" TabIndex="2" Text="Submit" />--%>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <asp:Label ID="lblTimer" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="text-dark text-small"></asp:Label>
    </div>
</form>

This is my code,
in the ASP button, I put the onClick() and OnClientClick() at the same time I need to work.
But it could not work.
below I provided the JavaScript function and also my code-behind function.
function startTimer() {
    startMinutes = 1; // Set the desired countdown time
    time = startMinutes * 60;
    btnSubmit.prop('disabled', true);
    btnSubmit.val('Resend');
    timerElement.style.display = 'block';

    if (!interval) {
        interval = setInterval(updateTimerCountdown, 1000);
    }

    return true; // Ensure postback happens
}

        protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Timer", "alert('button clicked!');", true);
        }

What I Tried:

JavaScript Function (startTimer): You wrote a JavaScript function that starts a timer and disables the button, expecting this to execute before the form submits.
ASP Button with OnClientClick and OnClick: You assigned OnClientClick to call the JavaScript function and OnClick to handle the server-side logic.

What I Expected:
I expected that when the button is clicked:
The

The startTimer JavaScript function would run, disabling the button and starting the timer.
The form would submit after the JavaScript function executes, triggering the server-side btnSubmit_Click event handler.
The alert "button clicked!" would display, confirming the server-side code ran.

What Happened:

Only the client-side JavaScript or the server-side code is executed, not both. The form submission might have been interrupted or the JavaScript might have prevented the postback from happening, leading to either:
The timer starts, but the server-side event (btnSubmit_Click) is not triggered.
The server-side event is being triggered, but the JavaScript not executing as expected.

